# "here" as a conjunction in a sence?

Tags: conjunctions

Is it correct to use "here" as a conjunction in written English?

For example:

> In comparison to first-generation devices, here, the system is built
>   from digital components.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd be inclined to call it an adverb, since in my view it modifies the verb "built".  But I've been wrong about such things before.

Comment: You also need to omit the second comma, since *here* is undoubtedly part of the second half of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"Here" is an adverb of place, either literally ("Come **here**!") or figuratively ("**Here**'s an idea:  stop annoying me.")  Your example is the latter usage, indicating the different place in the description for a system built from digital components.  You can look at the word as an aside, modifying the clause following.  It doesn't really modify the verb "built" as it would for somebody standing in factory and saying, "Cars are built **here**."